# What is the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot \cos ^2\left(\frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've tried to find sum to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^n} \cdot \cos ^2\left(\frac{2 n \pi}{3}\right)=\frac{2}{13}$, I know that the answer is $2/13$ but I don't get how to handle trigonometry functions in summation.

Can you show me your approach to this problem?

Comment: The cosine takes repeating values $0.25\; , \;0.25\; , \;1$. This gives you 3 sums for values $n=1,4,7,10,\ldots$ and $n=2,5,8,11,\ldots$ and $n=3,6,9,12,\ldots$ In the next step you should re-index the sum so that the index takes values $1,2,3,4,\ldots $ again - in each of the three sums. Finally, calculate the sums by the known formula for geometric series.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://e.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:

$\bullet$ if $n\equiv 0 ~~mod~3$, then $\cos\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}\right) = 1$.

$\bullet$ if $n\equiv 1 ~~mod~3$, then $\cos\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

$\bullet$ if $n\equiv 2 ~~mod~3$, then $\cos\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}$.

Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^n} \cos^2\left(\dfrac{2n\pi}{3}\right)= \\
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[
\dfrac{1}{3^{3k+1}} \cos^2\left(\dfrac{2(3k+1)\pi}{3}\right) +
\dfrac{1}{3^{3k+2}} \cos^2\left(\dfrac{2(3k+2)\pi}{3}\right) +
\dfrac{1}{3^{3k+3}} \cos^2\left(\dfrac{2(3k+3)\pi}{3}\right) \right] = \\
\dfrac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^{3k+1}} + 
\dfrac{1}{4} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^{3k+2}} + 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{3^{3k+3}} = 
\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{3}}{1-\frac{1}{27}} + 
\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{27}} +
\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{27}}{1-\frac{1}{27}} = \\
\dfrac{9}{104} + \dfrac{3}{104} + \dfrac{1}{26} = \frac{2}{13}.
$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\in\Bbb R$, and $|x|<1$. Define
$$f(x,y)=\sum_{n\ge1}x^ne^{iny}=\sum_{n\ge1}(xe^{iy})^n=\frac{xe^{iy}}{1-xe^{iy}}.$$
Then
$$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(f(x,y)+f(x,-y))=\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\frac{1}{2}(e^{iny}+e^{-iny})=\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\cos(ny).$$
Thus $$g(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{xe^{iy}}{1-xe^{iy}}+\frac{xe^{-iy}}{1-xe^{-iy}}\right)=\frac12\cdot\frac{x(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})-2x^2}{1-(e^{iy}+e^{-iy})x+x^2}=\frac{x(\cos y-x)}{1-2x\cos y+x^2}$$
From the cosine double angle formula, $\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos(2x)),$ so
$$\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\cos^2(ny)=\frac12\sum_{n\ge1}x^n(1+\cos(2ny))\\
=\frac12\left(\sum_{n\ge1}x^n+\sum_{n\ge1}x^n\cos(2ny)\right)=\frac12\left(\frac{x}{1-x}+g(x,2y)\right).$$
Thus your sum is given by
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{\cos^2(2\pi n/3)}{3^n}&=\frac12\left(\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}+g(1/3,4\pi/3)\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\tfrac13(\cos(4\pi/3)-\tfrac13)}{1-\tfrac23\cos(4\pi/3)+(\tfrac13)^2}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{5}{26}\right)\\
&=\frac{2}{13}.
\end{align}$$

Comment: This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.